# Java RMI Factory - ClassCastException

Tags: java, rmi, factory

I'm trying to create an RMI factory but I keep getting the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to remote.pkg.ContractDataFactory
```

I've never worked with the RMI protocol before so has been a lot of guess work to get to this state but now I'm completely lost as to why $Proxy0 can't correctly be cast?

All the reading and other examples I've looked are not trying to implement via a factory pattern so I'm not sure that is where my issue is?

The main entry point to the application:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    try {
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        Naming.rebind("FactoryTest", new ContractDataImpl(""));

    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Thread a = new FactoryTest("A");
    a.start();

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    Thread b = new FactoryTest("B");
    b.start();

    a.join();
    b.join();

    System.exit(0);
}
```

Here is the run method from the FactoryTest class that I'm running

```
public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Getting a remote handle to a factory. " + this.hashCode());

        ContractDataFactory factory = (ContractDataFactory) Naming.lookup("FactoryTest");
        ContractDataRemote worker = factory.getClient();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This creates an instance of ContractDataFactory which looks like:

```
interface ContractDataFactory extends Remote {

public ContractDataRemote getClient() throws RemoteException;

}
```

and ContractDataRemote looks like:

```
public interface ContractDataRemote extends Remote, DB {

}
```

DB is simply another interface with all the actual methods required to do the work.

Hopefully this is enough information to help me solve this?

Cheers.

Edit:
Included the contents of ContractDataFactoryImpl

```
class ContractDataFactoryImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ContractDataFactory {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1337;

private static String dbLocation = null;

public ContractDataFactoryImpl(String dbLocation) throws RemoteException {
    ContractDataFactoryImpl.dbLocation = dbLocation;
}

@Override
public ContractDataRemote getClient() throws RemoteException {
    return new ContractDataImpl(dbLocation);
}
}
```

Comment: Post the definition of `ContractDataFactoryImpl`. Do all the methods of `DB` throw `RemoteException` or `IOException`?

Comment: Hi, all DB methods throw RemoteException - Have edited the question to include the requested class

Comment: And are the package names consistent between client and server? This problem can be caused by copying the remote interfaces into a different package in the client side.

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: @EJP All packages accept DB are in the same package (remote.pkg).

Comment: @AnubianNoob The error is thrown at the class cast which is about line 5 of the run method in FactoryTest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Naming.rebind("FactoryTest", new ContractDataImpl(""));
```

That should be

```
Naming.rebind("FactoryTest", new ContractDataFactoryImpl(""));
```